# Azure Deployment Failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, migration, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application which is hosted on the azure cloud. I made a few database changes by adding two new columns to a table. After updating the migrations for the local database and building the application successfully, I tried to publish the changes to Azure. Before publishing I updated the remote databases which was successful.

But during publish to Azure. I recieved the following error and now my site is not opening anymore and it is showing a 500 error.

[image]

Error in plain text :
Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
Error        Web deployment task failed. (An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
The Element or Annotation class SqlDatabaseOptions does not contain the Property class CatalogCollation.
The Element or Annotation class SqlDatabaseOptions does not contain the Property class CatalogCollation.
Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.)    DemoShmotiAppl        0

I created a new app service on Azure and tried to publish, but I still get the same error.

I am running Visual Studio 2017 15.6.4 with the latest Azure SDK.

Comment: What about the CatalogCollation property and Mvc.FixedDisplayModes packages in your project? Could you provide more details and the migration code. And it seems that the new  [package version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes) is 5.0.

Comment: Do you have database publishing enabled for your deployment? Since you already updated your db, I don't think you need to do that.

Comment: @JasonP yes updated my db remotely and again had enabled 'Update Database' in azure publish settings. A microsoft tech guy called up and just asked me to republish and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had enabled 'Update Database' setting in azure publish window even after remotely updating the database using PM console.

Just had to by unchecking 'Update Database'. It solved the issue.